# authentication failed while connecting to tfs using tfs api

Tags: c#, asp.net, tfs

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [authentication failed while connecting to tfs using tfs api](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13854147/authentication-failed-while-connecting-to-tfs-using-tfs-api)

I am facing a strange issue.I want to connect tfs server using tfs api programmitcally.
Even after giving proper authentcaion crediatials it is failing.But if I do it manually by typing tfs server name in browser its got connected.

code:

```
TeamFoundationServer tfs = 
      new TeamFoundationServer(new Uri("http://xx.xx.xx.xx:8080/tfs"), 
                        new NetworkCredential(@"user", "pass", "domain"));
tfs.EnsureAuthenticated()
```

Please suggest.

Comment: I really hope that isn't your actual ip and authentication details... If so I'd edit your question if I were you!

Answer (score 0):

You may want to use this [alternative](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb286958.aspx):

```
using Microsoft.TeamFoundation.Client;
using Microsoft.TeamFoundation.Framework.Client;
using Microsoft.TeamFoundation.Framework.Common;
using System;
using System.Collections.ObjectModel;

class Program
{
    static void Main()
    {
        var tfsUri = new Uri("http://xx.xx.xx.xx:8080/tfs");

        TfsConfigurationServer configurationServer =
                TfsConfigurationServerFactory.GetConfigurationServer(tfsUri);

        // Get the catalog of team project collections
        ReadOnlyCollection<CatalogNode> collectionNodes = configurationServer.CatalogNode.QueryChildren(
            new[] { CatalogResourceTypes.ProjectCollection },
            false, CatalogQueryOptions.None);

        // List the team project collections
        foreach (CatalogNode collectionNode in collectionNodes)
        {
            // Use the InstanceId property to get the team project collection
            Guid collectionId = new Guid(collectionNode.Resource.Properties["InstanceId"]);
            TfsTeamProjectCollection teamProjectCollection = configurationServer.GetTeamProjectCollection(collectionId);

            // Print the name of the team project collection
            Console.WriteLine("Collection: " + teamProjectCollection.Name);

            // Get a catalog of team projects for the collection
            ReadOnlyCollection<CatalogNode> projectNodes = collectionNode.QueryChildren(
                new[] { CatalogResourceTypes.TeamProject },
                false, CatalogQueryOptions.None);

            // List the team projects in the collection
            foreach (CatalogNode projectNode in projectNodes)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(" Team Project: " + projectNode.Resource.DisplayName);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do it [a simpler way](https://bitbucket.org/mrshrinkray/spruce/src/5809d7787e29c73874e531764f435b3f4bce8caa/Spruce.Core/UserContext.cs?at=default) (assuming you have pass through auth):

```
var tfsCollection = new TfsTeamProjectCollection(new Uri("http://yourtfs:8080/tfs/"));
tfsCollection.Authenticate();
var workItemStore = new WorkItemStore(TfsCollection);
```