# authentication failed while connecting to tfs using tfs api

Tags: c#, asp.net, tfs

I am facing a strange issue.I want to connect tfs server using tfs api programmitcally.
Even after giving proper authentcaion crediatials it is failing.But if I do it manually by typing tfs server name in browser its got connected.

code:

```
TeamFoundationServer tfs = new TeamFoundationServer(new Uri("http://10.112.205.145:8080/tfs"),  new NetworkCredential(@"usrname", "pwd", "domain"));
tfs.EnsureAuthenticated()
```

Please suggest.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you tried doing it this way..

```
TfsTeamProjectCollection collection = new TfsTeamProjectCollection(
    new Uri(http://server:8080/tfs/DefaultCollection,
    new System.Net.NetworkCredential("domain_name\\user_name", "pwd"));
collection.EnsureAuthenticated();
```

Comment: still not working.its saying you are not authorized to access tfs servername

Comment: Ok - try the following - install TFS Power Tools and check that everything security related is ok.. Have you installed VS2010 SP1?

Comment: If you have then go into the internet settings (i do it through IE > Internet Options) and adding the path to your TFS server to the trusted sites list in the Security tab.

Comment: or - apply the make requests on behalf of others permission on the default collection..

Comment: Hi Shipu, Which thing worked for you? There are 3 options given by The Unculled Badger

Answer (score 4):

A simple way to do this is to add the "Syetem.Net" namespace to your code and then use the "CredentialCache" object. Using "DefaultCredentials" will Authenticate with the credentials of the active user.

```
// connect to the collection
using (TfsTeamProjectCollection teamProjectCollection = new TfsTeamProjectCollection("http://server:8080/tfs/DefaultCollection", CredentialCache.DefaultCredentials))
            { 
                //Do Stuff here 
            }
```

Comment: I had interpreted this question as the OP wanting to use a specific user possibly with elevated rights..

Comment: Thats a fair enough assumption, Not sure about leaving credentials with elevated privileges in code though :-)

Answer (score 0):

For your problem, normally you get an error like:

Possible reasons for failure include:
- The name, port number, or protocol for the Team Foundation Server is incorrect.
- The Team Foundation Server is offline.
- The password has expired or is incorrect.

The root cause of your problem is that **the URI should be ended up with the collection name**. So the fix would be, to change "http://10.112.205.145:8080/tfs" to "http://10.112.205.145:8080/tfs/**%YourCollectionName%**", then it will work! :-)